# Можно ли с помощью php создавать файлы с расширением .php ?

Tags: joomla, php

Дело в том что я недавно более менее освоил написание модулей и компонентов для joomla и теперь хочу написать простой скрипт который будет представлять из себя небольшую форму с десятком полей, куда бы можно было ввести название компонента, его версию, автора, параметры, нажать кнопку "создать" и скрипт самостоятельно создавал "заготовку" под компонент, т.е. 2 папки admin и site, файл Название.xml файлы controller.php, точку входа Название.php  и т.д. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Можно... Главное соблюдать последовательность!

Comment: А более конкретно? Ну там функции какие-нибудь или ещё что? =) Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$code = '
    <?php
    // Код PHP файла
';
file_put_contents('/Путь_к_файлу/Имя_файла.php', $code);
```

У вас должны быть права на запись в папку в которой вы хотите создавать файлы

Answer (score 4):

Конечно можно. Относись к файлу с кодом скрипта, как к простому текстовому файлу.

```
fopen('new.php','w+')
```

Comment: Работает и то и то! Спасибо! ф функции file_put_content , опечатка, на конце упущена s Ещё раз всем спасибо! Как напишу скрипт - поделюсь в этом посте.

Answer (score 1):

Точнее, как к бинарному.